# Are the critical points of a function $f(x)$ the same as the minimum and maximum values?

Tags: calculus

I had thought the inflection points were also critical points, though the sources I read say critical points of $f(x)$ are where: $f'(x) = 0$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CriticalPoi...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_p...

I have a question asking about the critical points of a cubic and the minimum maximum values. I wonder why they would ask for both if they are the same thing?

Comment: Inflection points typically refer to the second derivative. As to your title question, critical points to $f(x)$ are *not* the same as the min/max values.

Comment: Consider the classic example $f(x)=x^3$. What are the critical points? Does this function have any local maxima or minima?

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking at this and I think I understand the distinction:   $f(x) = (x-5)^3$ ... Has a critical point at x = 5 but this is neither a local min or max, like $f(x) = x^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Critical points (of a differentiable function) are precisely those with $f'(x)=0$. Such a point *may* be a local extremum, it *may* also be a point of inflection (and there may be points of inflection with $f'(x)\ne0$). Recall that not *all* points with $f'(x)=0$ are local extrema.

When you look for local extrema, you actually first look for critical poits (which is just a fancy way of saying you solve $f'(x)=0$). Once you have found these, you check these individually - some will be local maxima, some local minima, some neither. So the concepts are related, but not the same.

Comment: A critical point may also arise when $f'(x)$ does not exist, even if $f(x)$ exists. For example, if $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$, then $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$ which doesn't exist if $x=0$. In fact, the slope of the graph of $f(x)$ at $(0,0)$ is infinite